Systemd user timer lost on reboot
My Systemd user timers are lost after a reboot. I've enabled them with systemctl --user enable --now x.timer and enabled lingering. Immediately after enabling the timers, they start up normally and are listed under systemctl --user list-timers. But after a reboot, the timers are all inactive again.
OS is Debian 12
After reboot:
$ systemctl --user list-timers --all
NEXT LEFT LAST PASSED UNIT ACTIVATES

0 timers listed.

Enabling the timers, they run normally until the next reboot:
$ systemctl --user enable --now x.timer

$ systemctl --user list-timers
NEXT                        LEFT           LAST                        PASSED     UNIT    
Sat 2024-04-27 14:21:22 EDT 1h 19min left  -                           -          x.timer

Also, after a reboot when the timers are lost, systemctl --list-dependencies shows the timer but it is not enabled:
$ systemctl --user list-dependencies timers.target 
timers.target
○ └─x.timer

After enabling the timer:
$ systemctl --user list-dependencies timers.target 
timers.target
● └─x.timer

x.service:
[Unit]
Description=redacted description

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redacted

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

x.timer
[Unit]
Description=redacted description
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 1,9,17:30:00
RandomizedDelaySec=1h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target


Answering my own question:
My user directories are mounted on a separate disk (a btrfs raid array) than my OS, and the user@.service was being started before the disk was finished mounting. The user@.service has a drop-in override file installed by default which adds an After=systemd-user-sessions.service, so I added another drop-in override to systemd-user-sessions.service which adds a dependency to my mount.
$ systemctl cat systemd-user-sessions.service 
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-user-sessions.service
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Permit User Sessions
Documentation=man:systemd-user-sessions.service(8)
After=remote-fs.target nss-user-lookup.target network.target home.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-user-sessions start
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-user-sessions stop

# /etc/systemd/system/systemd-user-sessions.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
After=srv-mybtrfsarray.mount


To fix this, ensure that the systemd-user service is enabled and started:
systemctl enable systemd-user
systemctl start systemd-user
This service is responsible for managing user systemd services and timers.
Additionally, make sure that the lingering option is enabled for your user:
loginctl show-user <username> | grep Lingering
If it's not enabled, you can enable it with:
loginctl enable-linger <username>
After making these changes, re-enable your timers and double check that they persist after a reboot.
If you continue to experience these strange issues, examine the Systemd logs for any errors or warnings related to your timers or user services.
Edit for asker
Thanks for letting me know in the comments!
The absence of the systemd-user service is a key clue.
Try enabling the user systemd manager service to start automatically on boot:
systemctl enable user@$(whoami)
Obviously replacing whoami with your actual user name.
If this also doesn't work, I’d also try checking the user systemd manager logs:
journalctl -u user@$(whoami)
Remember that user systemd services and timers are stored in ~/.config/systemd/user/, so make sure that your user timers are located in this directory and have the correct ownership and permissions.
Second Edit
I think the error message "The unit files have no installation config" indicates that the user@1000.service file is not meant to be enabled or started directly.
Because the service is already started on boot, and there are no errors in the user journal, you were right, I think the issue might be related to the timers themselves, like you said.
Firstly verify that the timer files are located in ~/.config/systemd/user/ and have the correct ownership and permissions.
Check the timer files for any little typos, which sounds like stupid advice, but actually a lot of the time this is a common reason for things not working, as code and commands must be so exact, one little typo could stuff it up.
Also run: systemctl --user status <timer_name>.timer to check their status.
If everything looks correct, let’s look at bit deeper into the timer activation process.
Try running systemd-analyze plot > boot.html (as the user) and inspect the graphical boot chart to see if there are any issues or delays around the time the timers should be starting.
Seeing as this issue is a bit strange, there are many different issues that could be causing it, so you’ll just have to keep trying and trying until it’s fixed- because here’s the thing- every computer problem, no matter how hard, is fixable.
Ok, maybe not every computer problem, but I’m sure this one is!

Lingering is enabled, but there isn't a service called systemd-user. Jounalctl also doesn't show anything out of the ordinary as far as I can tell - on reboot, timers.target is reached and the system timers start, but user timers don't start until I manually start them.

Check my question again- the absence is a clue!

user@1000.service can't be enabled because "The unit files have no installation config", but I'm not sure that's the problem, that service is already started immediately on boot before any logins. No errors in user journal either.

I edited my question again, I’ve explained how to get a deeper look into the boot sequence and explained (if you didn’t already know,) how to check the clock status etc.

If the service/time is in user's home - is the home directory local or remote? If remote - does it require any form of authentication (like kerberos) to mount? And BTW if the x.service is to be triggered by timer it probably shouldn't have [Install] section.

@Tomek The user directory is mounted on a local disk - a btrfs raid array on a different disk than the OS. I noticed in systemd-analyze plot that timers.target was reached before the disk was fully mounted (the dark red bar of the mount extends beyond timers.target), could this be the issue? How would I fix this?

Made it work by adding a drop-in override for  systemd-user-sessions.service containing After=mydisk.mount
